# ¿Còmo puedo manejar las cookies desde mi archivo Web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp, web.config

Tengo una clase con un servicio de `Cookie` en la cual el método que crea la `Cookie` recibe 2 parámetros para finalmente crearla.

Mi método:

```
public static void SetCookie(string data, string name)
{
    HttpCookie httpCookie = new HttpCookie(name);
    httpCookie.Domain = "localhost";
    httpCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
    httpCookie.Value = ProtectCookieMethod(data);
    httpCookie.HttpOnly = true;
    httpCookie.Secure = false;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
}
```

Ahora lo que quiero hacer, es poder manejar desde mi archivo `Web.config` la mayor parte de las configuraciones que tengo en el metodo y si es necesario tener el metodo o bastaria solo con tener todas las configuraciones en el `Web.config`

Comment: ¿A qué configuraciones te refieres? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo del resultado que esperas obtener? Esto con el fin de poder entender por completo tu pregunta

Comment: es colocar todas las configuraciones en el <httpCookie> del Web.Config

Comment: Esa sección no te sirve. Deberás implementar tu propia sección de configuración y leer de ahí.

Answer (score 0):

Para implementar una sección personalizada en el `web.config` lo primero que necesitas es implementar una clase que derive de `ConfigurationSection`

```
using System.Configuration;
public class HttpCookiesCustomSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    // Create a "domain" attribute.
    [ConfigurationProperty("domain", DefaultValue = "", IsRequired =true)]
    public string Domain
    {
        get
        {
            return this["domain"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            this["domain"] = value;
        }
    }

    // Create a "httpOnly" attribute.
    [ConfigurationProperty("httpOnly", DefaultValue = false, IsRequired = true)]
    public bool HttpOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this["httpOnly"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["httpOnly"] = value;
        }
    }

    // Create a "secure" attribute.
    [ConfigurationProperty("secure", DefaultValue = false, IsRequired = true)]
    public bool Secure
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this["secure"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["secure"] = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Luego debes incluir en tu `web.config` un `sectionGroup` con un elemento `section` y luego tu configuración personalizada

```
<configuration>
<!-- Configuration section-handler declaration area. -->
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="httpCookiesCustomGroup">
      <section 
        name="httpCookiesCustom" 
        type="ConsoleApp.HttpCookiesCustomSection"
        allowLocation="true" 
        allowDefinition="Everywhere"
      />
    </sectionGroup>
      <!-- Other <section> and <sectionGroup> elements. -->
  </configSections>

  <!-- Configuration section-handler declaration area. -->

  <!-- Configuration section settings area. -->
  <httpCookiesCustomGroup>
    <httpCookiesCustom domain="MIDOMAIN" httpOnly="true" secure="true"  /> 
  </httpCookiesCustomGroup>

  <!-- Other configuration settings, such as system.web -->   

</configuration>
```

Luego para leer la configuración debes hacer algo así

```
var config = (ConsoleApp.HttpCookiesCustomSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("httpCookiesCustomGroup/httpCookiesCustom");
```

Comment: Pero... y la forma en que se hace todo directamente desde el Web.config? con los tags <httpCookie></httpCookie>

Comment: Revisa la documentación de [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228262(v=vs.100).aspx)